# problemMatcher: '$gcc' no funciona sobre SSH

Tags: gcc, vscode

He conseguido realizar tareas de compilación remotas sobre SSH, utilizando el siguiente `tasks.json`:

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "make all",
      "type": "process",
      "problemMatcher": "$gcc",
      "command": "ssh",
      "args": [ "-i", "D:\\Claves SSH\\id_rsa", "ilos@214.25.250.55", "make", "-C", "svn/CORE_SG/CFGP/Linux_Debug", "all" ],
      "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

La compilación funciona correctamente, **pero** por algún motivo que se me escapa, los errores se muestran **solo** en la pestaña `TERMINAL`:

> ../src/acciones/acciones_ventana_sdcs_interfaces_serie.c:490: error: two or more data types in declaration of 'on_btn_1_frm_1_frm_2_interfaces_serie_sdcs_clicked'
> ../src/acciones/acciones_ventana_sdcs_interfaces_serie.c:491: error: expected ')' before '{' token
> make: Leaving directory `/media/sf_cms/Subversion/CORE_SG/CFGP/Linux_Debug'
> make: *** [src/acciones/acciones_ventana_sdcs_interfaces_serie.o] Error 1
> El proceso del terminal finalizó con el código de salida: 2

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tal y como se observa en la imagen superior, hay un error de compilación. Yo espero que dicho error aparezca en la pestaña `PROBLEMAS`, permitiéndome saltar al archivo/línea con un solo *click* del ratón. Pero esto **no es así**: solo se muestran los errores del propio VSCode (tales como archivos de cabecera no encontrados):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy usando Visual Studio Code para Windows:

> Versión: 1.33.1 (user setup)
> Commit: 51b0b28134d51361cf996d2f0a1c698247aeabd8
> Fecha: 2019-04-11T08:27:14.102Z
> Electron: 3.1.6
> Chrome: 66.0.3359.181
> Node.js: 10.2.0
> V8: 6.6.346.32
> OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.15063

#### Edito

Como sugieren en los comentarios, he cambiado la propiedad `problemMatcher` para que sea un *array*:

```
"problemMatcher": [ "$gcc" ],
```

Con el mismo resultado: sigue sin mostrar adecuadamente los errores en la pestaña `PROBLEMAS`.

- ¿ Qué estoy haciendo mal ?
- ¿ Cómo lo soluciono ?

Comment: No se si esto ayuda en algo, en la documentación el valor de `problemMatcher` es un tipo `Array`, así: `"problemMatcher": ["$gcc"]`, sin embargo tu lo tienes como un tipo `String` así:  `"problemMatcher": "$gcc"`.

Comment: @MauricioContreras Gracias, acabo de probarlo. Sin cambios, sigue sin indicar correctamente los errores :'-(

Comment: Ok, seguire investigando. XD

Comment: Al parecer debes crear tu propio patrón para `problemMatcher`. ¿Le has echado un ojo a esto: [Defining a Problem Matcher](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_defining-a-problem-matcher)?

Comment: @MauricioContreras Se que existe la posibilidad, pero me gustaría no tener que llegar a ello; después de todo, el `problemMatcher: "$gcc"` ya está existe. Esperaré un par de días por si alguien responde, y si no ... pues habrá que *ensuciarse las manos* :-(